# Explicit Instantiation declaration

Tags: c++, templates

**EDITED MY QUESTION PLEASE HELP :(**

Need a little help.
I'm using STL vector and I have these files:
vectorAux.h, vectorDriver.cpp, and vectorAux.cpp

I want to link this and compile it. I originally asked about explicit instantiation but I realize this route was not the way I wanted. I was just hoping it would help me fix my issue of compiling it.

I'm doing this for homework, and in the directions it says to "#include vectorAux.cpp" at the bottom of this header file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#ifndef VECTORAUX_H
#define VECTORAUX_H

template<typename T>
void writeVector(const vector<T>&vect);

template<typename T>
int seqVectSearch(const vector<T>&vect, int first, int last, const T&target);

template<typename T>
void removeDup(vector<T>&vect);

#endif
```

Long story short, I couldn't make that work, so I tried to look at an old project I had a while back. The real problem is that I don't understand how to link templates, I realize you can include implementations in the header file, but my teachers simply do NOT like this at all.

They prefer that I separate things and/or include cpp files...

Really I'm just utterly confused... Last year I asked a very similar question and after a few hours finally managed to compile it, but the user that answered my question told me to figure out why it compiled, but of course I still don't understand as I'm having this issue again...

So my question in short is, how can I fix my code to make things compile?

I removed the instantiation file since you said I cannot explicitly instantiate functions, but I still get this error in my driver:

http://prntscr.com/8qq397/direct

Here's the code I am using to declare it, but it cannot find anything that matches the argument list:

```
/*
vectorAux.cpp
Implementations of Template Functions

COSC220   Lab 7
*/

#include "vectorAux.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void removeDup(std::vector<T> & v)
{
}


template <typename T>
unsigned seqVectSearch(const std::vector<T> & v, unsigned first, unsigned last, const T& target){
// Complete the code, use sequential search for arrays as model
return last; // if not found, return last
}

template <typename T>
void writeVector(const std::vector<T> & v){
    unsigned i;
    unsigned n = v.size();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << v[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Here's my driver:

```
#include "vectorAux.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// fill vector with values
void fillVector(std::vector<int> & vect);

int main()
{
using namespace std;

// Declare an empty vector of int
vector<int> vect;

// Test removeDuplicate
// Fill vector with vals, write it to console
fillVector(vect);
cout << "Testing removeDup" << endl;
cout << "Original vector is  ";
writeVector(vect);

// Remove the duplicates, write it to console again
removeDup(vect);
cout << "Vector with duplicates removed is  ";
writeVector(vect);
cout << endl;
writeVector(vect);
return 0;
}

void fillVector(std::vector<int> & vect){
int arr[] = {1,7,2,7,9,1,2,8,9};
unsigned arrsize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
vect = std::vector<int>(arr, arr+arrsize);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have explicit instantiation of functions, functions doesn't exists as objects. You can however *specialize* a templated function:

```
template<>
void writeVector(const vector<int>&vect);
```

The above declares a specialization of the `writeVector` function for `int`. This can then be implemented in a source file like any other function. (Note that you don't actually have to declare the above function prototype, the templated prototype is enough, just implement (define) the function.)

Comment: How can I compile this? If I scratch the instantiation file, I cannot seem to get it to compile... where do I include #include "vectorAux.cpp" @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: @aaabbbaaa If you only want to use `std::vector<int>` why are you using templated functions? Why not simple explicitly declare (and define) the *non* template function `void writeVector(const vector<int>&vect)`?

Comment: it's for class... I don't know lol She wants us to practice templates

Comment: @aaabbbaaa Then *declare* the template function in your header file, and *define* the specialized function in a source file. That's all you need to do. If you have problems or errors you need to show some actual code (like a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) to us, together with the actual errors from that code.

Comment: sorry I got a little confused on your answer, so I don't have to put the prototype, but every time I wish to use a new version of it I have to write a whole new implementation?   EDIT: I cannot declare it in the header file. my teacher hates this... I'll try declaring it one sec... This is preferred in the driver or the other cpp I have?

Comment: @aaabbbaaa Yes that's correct. At least if you want explicit behavior depending on type.

Comment: I actually dont need it to be explicit behavior I was just trying to get it to compile... haha is there an easier way to do this @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: im sorry for bothering you so much... im really stuck.. Can I make this compile without the explicit instantiation

Comment: *"You can't have explicit instantiation of functions"*, you can

Comment: @aaabbbaaa in file `vectorAux.cpp` add (at the end) the following three lines: `template void removeDup(std::vector<int> & v); template 
unsigned seqVectSearch(const std::vector<int> & v, unsigned first, unsigned last, const int& target); template void writeVector(const std::vector<int> & v);`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki just tried that but I get a build failed. can I show you a print / output? http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dbvDyRQb

Comment: @aaabbbaaa 1. remove `#include "vectorAux.cpp"` from a header file (if you have it), 2. add `#include <vector>` to the `vectorAux.h` file

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki im gonna die. thank u LOl holy hell. .. it wasnt compiling because i didnt include the vector header in my .h file :@